# Array of structs as Generic value

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to use an array of structs as a generic parameter as follows:

```
new Test<S[,]>()
```

This is easy, except for my class needs to create an instance of `T` as follows:

```
T s = new T();
```

This is giving me various compile-time errors. I have tried a few ways of getting around these errors, but without success.

Here is some sample code to illustrate the errors and what I have tried:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = new Test<S[,]>();

        // ERROR: 'Program.S[*,*]' must be a non-abstract type
        // with a public parameterless constructor in order to
        // use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
        // 'Program.Test2<T>'
        var t2 = new Test2<S[,]>();

        // ERROR: 'Program.S[*,*]' must be a non-nullable value
        // type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic
        // type or method 'Program.Test3<T>'
        var t3 = new Test3<S[,]>();

        // ERROR: 'Program.S[*,*]' must be a non-nullable value
        // type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic
        // type or method 'Program.Test3<T>'
        var t4 = new Test4<S[,]>();
    }

    struct S
    {
    }

    class Test<T>
    {
        // ERROR: Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T'
        // because it does not have the new() constraint
        T s = new T();
    }

    class Test2<T> where T: new()
    {
        T s = new T();
    }

    class Test3<T> where T: struct
    {
        T s = new T();
    }

    // ERROR: The 'new()' constraint cannot be used with the 'struct' constraint
    class Test4<T> where T : struct, new()
    {
        T s = new T();
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way around this issue?

Comment: You can't initialize an array without specifying its size, so in a sense it doesn't have a parameterless constructor, therefore you can't do `T s = new T();` when `T` is an `array type`. You might want to use a `List<T>` or `List<List<T>>` if that meets your needs.

Comment: ```T s = new T();``` what value you expect here for an array?

Answer (score 0):

Your error gives you the answer. new() constraint can not be used for structure(both new() and struct constraint can not be used together).
So unless it is imperative to have S as structure, I would change S to class and get rid of problem. But you must have S as structure then workaround I suggest is to create a wraper class.

```
public class Wraper
{
    Wrapper(){}
    Wrapper(S value){
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public S Value {get; set;}

    public static implicit operator S(Wrapper wrapper){
        return wrapper. Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Wraper(S s){
        return new Wrapper(S);
    }
}
```

Now you can define your Test as the following:

```
class Test<T> where T : Wrapper, new()
{
    T value;

    //as you have provided implicit conversion from S to Wrapper and vice versa
    //something like this should work
    public S Value{
        get{ 
            //implicit conversion from Wrapper to S;
            return this.Value;
        }

        set{
            //implicit conversion from S to Wrapper
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @rhughes did this answer solve your problem? If not let me know.

Comment: The answer is wrong. A `struct` __can__ be used with the constraint `where T : new()`. But an array type is not a `struct` type. Even if the element type of the array type is a `struct` type, that does not make the array type itself a value type. For example the array type `int[,]` is a reference type even if its element type `int` is a value type. Making a `WrapperOfInt[,]` will not help. Downvoting.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen revisit my answer. I meant struct & new()  constraint both can not be used together. So I suggested that a wrapper class and new() constraint can be used.

Comment: As soon as you have the constraint `where T : struct`, it is already permissible to say `new T()` inside the class. It is equivalent to `default(T)` in that case. That is the reason why it is not allowed to say `where T : struct, new()` - using `new()` together with `struct` introduces nothing new. None of this is particularly central to the question originally asked. And your answer about a wrapper is irrelevant.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I already know that. So your downvote reason might be irrelevance rather wrongfulness. Anyway I respect your point of view.

Comment: Wrapping that struct doesn't help, because the OP wants to use an *array* - and you can't `new` an array without knowing how many elements it should have.